# windows 7 ms updates stopped

Tags: windows-7, updates

I stopped the windows7 update process while it was downloading files.
(I have a laptop that is seldom used and has 76 updates to be applied.)

If I restart it, will it pickup where it was, or will it start over?

Sp1 is on.  I have 76 updates to be applied. I am using wi-fi(which shouldn't matter. I am in the process of downloading them.  Extremely slow, most of the down loads use less than 1% of capacity.  Long waits between downloads.

I stopped the downloads and connected to the direct lan connection I have on my desktop.   same thing,  just really poor performance!!

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: sp1 is on.  I have 76 updates to be applied. in the process of downloading.  download speed extremely slow, most of the under 1% of capacity, with long waits between downloads.   thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Yes, where it left off.

Also, if it's that far behind on updates it might be worth grabbing the convenience roll up. It has all those individual updates bundled into one. Then you'll just have about 11 months of patches to do. 
http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3125574